# Node JS my-sql query time is a lot slower than MySQL workbench query

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql-workbench

Basically, I have a table of around 70k rows - when I perform a select all query in nodejs using mysql it takes around 2s. However, MySQL workbench reports the same query takes around 0.05s. I'm pretty new to using nodejs - but here's some code.

```
this.acquire = function (callback) {
    this.pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        callback(err, connection);
    });
};

this.init = function () {
    this.pool = mysql.createPool({
        multipleStatements: true,
        connectionLimit: 100,
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'example',
        database: 'example',
    });
}
```

Then the query itself:

```
connection.acquire(function (err, con) {
   var table = "test"
   var query = "SELECT * FROM `" + table + "`";
   console.time("test");
   con.query(query, function (err, result) {
       console.timeEnd("test");
       con.release();
   });
}
```

which prints out *test: 1969ms*

And the result from MySQL workbench:
17:31:48    SELECT * FROM example.test  70001 row(s) returned   0.000 sec / 0.031 sec

The data structure itself is only 3 columns, an id, timestamp and an int. 
The question is, why is nodeJS query so much slower? Is it simply the connection time from the nodeJs app to the MySQL server, or is my nodeJs not setup properly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's a difference between running a query directly on the db versus gaining a connection, running the query, returning the results, and releasing the connection.

Comment: I would agree, but it doesn't really make much sense that it would take 63 times as long.

Comment: Don't underestimate the required work to setup structures etc. This really can take a lot longer than follow-up work. Compare only the query execution times after everything else is set up (MySQL Workbench also has quite a lot to do before it can run the first query).